# Add File/Registry using AppV 5.0

Tags: file, registry, virtual

How does one add a file or registry by editing a sequenced AppV 5.0 application?

Whenever we have tried to add a file directly under Root in the AppV 5.0 editor, the file was added to different location. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

The top directory of the package represents a location where some metadata files key to describing the package reside.  The directory literally named "Root" represents the primary virtual application directory. You should be successful adding files to this directory, or any of the VFS directories, but not to the top directory of the package itself.